# How can I output the variable name instead of the numerical OID with SNMP walk in python?

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp, snmpwalk

I'm writing a python script for an SNMP walk and want to print out the variable names along with their associated values. The code I'm currently using gives the numerical OIDs and their values. I have the MIB file - is there a way to output the variable names?

This is the code I'm using:

```
def walk_mib(ipaddress, oid):
    for (errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
           CommunityData('public'),
           UdpTransportTarget((ipaddress, 161)),
           ContextData(),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(oid)),
           ):

        if not errorIndication and not errorStatus:
            for varBind in varBinds:
                result=' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind])
                print(result)

walk_mib('<ip address>', start_oid)
```

It gives output like this: SNMPV2-SMI::[OID] = [value]
What I want is something like this: SNMPV2-SMI::[variableName] = [value]

Answer (score 0):

People do need to know which OID you are now WALKing by, so as to answer this question better.

In case the OID is under a private enterprise (for example Cisco related), you need to explicitly load the MIB document,

```py
snmpEngine = SnmpEngine()
mibBuilder = snmpEngine.getMibBuilder()

# Optionally compile MIBs
compiler.addMibCompiler(mibBuilder, sources=['/usr/share/snmp/mibs'])
    mibBuilder.addMibSources(builder.DirMibSource('/Users/someone/somefolder/mibs'))

mibBuilder.loadModule('CISCO-PRODUCTS-MIB')
```

You can then pass such an `snmpEngine` object to `nextCmd`.

Comment: I used mibdump.py to generate a .py version of the mib file (it's a custom mib from the vendor). I'm trying to get the object-type names from that